# R не устанавливает дополнительные пакеты

Tags: r

Использую R на компьютере 10-летнего возраста. Оперативная память всего 256 Mb. При попытке установить любой пакет получаю сообщение:

> error: c stack usage is too close to the limit

Проблема в малом объёме оперативной памяти или может быть в чем-то другом?

Answer (score 2):

Место на диске С: закончилось.